# Favoriting question shows as modified

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

When favoriting a question, it is immediately highlighted in the user's favorites tab, even though nothing has changed since it was favorited.

This makes it harder to find what's new in your older favorites if you've favorited recently.

[image]

Can we disable the highlighting until there's an actual change made in the time since favoriting?

Comment: Admit it, this is just to gain a badge from all the people who will now favorite it to reproduce! ;)

Comment: Interesting enough, if you favorite, unfavorite then favorite again, it won't be yellow.

Comment: ooh, nice workaround!